# Как узнать ip адрес клиента?

Tags: php, javascript

Как узнать ip адрес клиента?

Comment: jquery php javascript так поконкретнее на чем нужно узнать на jquery или php или javascript

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<?php 
  echo "<b>IP-адрес клиента:</b><br />".$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']."<hr />"; 
?>
```

Если для отправки через форму можно в Input загнать:

```
 <?php
   echo '<input type="hidden" name="person" value="'.$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'].'">';
 ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

в php:

```
echo '<script> var IP = "'.$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'].'"; alert(IP);</script>'
```

:)

Answer (score 1):

Также можно использовать такой код для **PHP**, подходит если пользователь сидит под прокси и прокси позволяет увидеть IP пользователя *(прозрачный/не анонимный)*.

```
<?php     
    if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'])) {
        $ip = $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
    } elseif (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'])) {
        $ip = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
    } else {
        $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    }
    echo 'User IP = ' . $ip;
?>
```

Однако стоит учитывать, что в заголовки **HTTP_CLIENT_IP** и **HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR** пользователь может записать что ему угодно.